# FontCreator fallback font issue

Tags: fonts

When I write font to test, it views correctly, but I when entered it to WordPad, it shows fallback font in Ğ,ğ,İ,Ş,ş characters. How can I fix it from font's properties?

Comment: You really need to give us much more data than this one sentence.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.